# How to create activity context dependent object in dagger?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, inject, dagger

I have a situation, I have injected all objects using Dagger 2, But in one situation I am unable to rectify how to inject the object.

Following is the situation

```
mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(this));
```

Now in the above statement, I have to inject the MyPagerAdapter object using Dagger, but it requires current activity context.

So how to forward the activity context to the Dagger module?

Comment: Module constructor parameter

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Can you please add some code resolving the above situation will help.

Comment: `@Module @ActivityScope public class MyModule { private Activity activity; public MyModule(Activity activity) { this.activity = activity;} ...`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Thanks I will try it out

Comment: Does someone want to turn this into an answer? I don't think this exact question has been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(turning @EpicPandaForce's comment into an answer)

You can write a module that takes an Activity in its constructor parameters like this:

```
@Module
@ActivityScope 
public class MyModule {
    private final Activity activity;

    public MyModule(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    Activity activity() {
        return activity;
    }
}
```